# How to fix java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:: io.searchbox.client.config.idle.ReapableConnectionManager

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

Hi When i try to configure jest client I got

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:: io.searchbox.client.config.idle.ReapableConnectionManager.

I use the mvn dependency of searchbox is .
`<dependency>
    <groupId>io.searchbox</groupId>
    <artifactId>jest</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.7</version>
</dependency>`
. After seeing the error i found the class

> Reapableconnectionmanager,which is already exist there.
>   Is any one guide me to fix this error .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you invoke the client?

Comment: Using this code i invoke the client `HttpClientConfig clientConfig = new HttpClientConfig.Builder(Arrays.asList(getSetting(S_ES_POINT).split(","))).multiThreaded(true)
    .maxTotalConnection(500).defaultMaxTotalConnectionPerRoute(100).readTimeout(30000).build();` and the S_ES_POINT value is `S_ES_POINT("search.elasticsearch.point", "localhost:9160");`.

Comment: Your class path at runtime is broken.

Comment: Thanks for your response Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen.After i remove the split function it works fine